# Web Scraping a specific table data in R

Tags: r, xml, web-scraping

Ho can I scrape table data in R, dynamically? I have a website "http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/goog/option-chain?dateindex=1" and I want to get the "OpenChain" table data and "Greeks" table data for multiple dates and multiple companies. How can I do that in R. I want to use R because the above data needs to be modeled further and I want to stick to one language for doing the whole thing. Thanks in advance.

Current code below is returning a NULL "stock" dataframe:

```
    #Getting the webpage 
    urls= rbindlist(
    lapply(pages, function(x){ 
    url=paste("nasdaq.com/symbol/goog/option-chain?";, sep="") 
    data.frame(url) 
    })
    , fill=TRUE)

    #Getting table data 
    stock=rbindlist(
    apply(urls, 1, function(url){
    doc1=htmlParse(url) 
    stockprices=getNodeSet(doc1,'//*[@id="optionchain"]/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[1]') 
    data.frame(sapply(stockprices, function(x){xmlValue(x)}))
    }
    ), fill = TRUE)
```

Comment: What is the code that you have written so far?

Comment: #Getting the webpage
urls= rbindlist(lapply(pages, function(x){
  url=paste("http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/goog/option-chain?", sep="")
  data.frame(url)
}
), fill=TRUE)


#Getting table data
stock=rbindlist(apply(urls, 1, function(url){
  doc1=htmlParse(url)
  stockprices=getNodeSet(doc1, '//*[@id="optionchain"]/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[1]')
  data.frame(sapply(stockprices, function(x){xmlValue(x)}))
}), fill = TRUE)

The code is returning a NULL "stock" dataframe.

Comment: you should check out the [rvest package](https://blog.rstudio.org/2014/11/24/rvest-easy-web-scraping-with-r/)